# How to fill username and password with selenium on a page where IDs are hidden?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to fill the username and password with python code. Though the code successfully opens the page it does not fill the username and password section. I am attaching the code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors=yes')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get('https://120.72.92.102:10443/remote/login?lang=en')
username = driver.find_element_by_id("Name")
password = driver.find_element_by_id("password")

username.send_keys("YourUsername")
password.send_keys("PassworD")

driver.find_element_by_name("Login").click()
```

The image of the page looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have picked the wrong ids from the page. The ones you have picked are `type` attribute and not ids.
You can use the below code to operate on the page(Have picked the correct ids) and have applied explicit wait on the first element:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors=yes')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get('https://120.72.92.102:10443/remote/login?lang=en')
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "username")))

username = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
password = driver.find_element_by_id("credential")

username.send_keys("YourUsername")
password.send_keys("PassworD")

driver.find_element_by_id("login_button").click()
```

Comment: It worked! Great. Thanks a lot, man! I do not want to bother you much but I will really appreciate if you can tell me how did you determine correct ids and what does WebDriverWait do here?

Comment: @PranjalPathak I have used an explicit wait here which waits till the element is present on the page. And if you inspect the element and check its html, you can find an attribute named as `id` so from there i got the ids

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is a great help.